# Xcode quit unexpectedly Dyld Error message symbol not found _ASI_CopyHostUUID

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

When I want launch the xcode, this doesn't open and show me this message "Xcode quit unexpectedly" and the report is:

```
Process:               Xcode [2585]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.1 (7703)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7703000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812230896
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [2585]
User ID:               393298473

Date/Time:             2015-05-14 13:36:02.941 -0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F6EF1A43-CD47-CDDB-8754-7B593A5DBE45


Time Awake Since Boot: 8200 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D1002

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _ASI_CopyHostUUID
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
  Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSystemInfo.framework/Versions/A/AppleSystemInfo
```

How can I make it open?

Answer (score -1):

When I had a `EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)` exception I used terminal to navigate to the `Expected in:` part of the Dyld error message.

For my problem I could remove the file that was being referred to by the `Expected in:` part of the Dyld error message.

I hope this helps you out.

## EDIT:

I do not advise that you remove the `system private frameworks`. Sorry for the careless wording.

What I meant was that if you go to `Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSystemInfo.framework/Versions/A/AppleSystemInfo` you might find what needs to be changed.

Comment: Recommending the removal of **system private frameworks** to address the execution error like this will probably break his computer.